# What is the meaning of the ^[OP in terminal?

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, pxe

Ok-- so I've got a mystery on my hands.

I'm currently manually PXE installing via IPMI, working in the terminal, and throughout the process of watching the terminal display information regarding the installation, I keep seeing `^[OP` being repeated over and over--like someone is sitting on the keyboard.

The closest I've gotten to discovering what key this could be is [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222901/caret-square-bracket-square-bracket-a-a-what-does-it-mean?newreg=169aea8423af473794685c1565ec43b6)

However, I can find no documentation of what the `OP` portion represents.

This happens on multiple devices I've used with different keyboards, so it is not a keyboard malfunction. It also does not occur on other machines running the same installers.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: (expanding off of the accepted answer) Ok so extension on the mystery. I'm pretty sure these codes only return if the system does not know how to deal with the input. It only shows up at a random point during the installation--and when I try to hit the F1 key to force the ^[OP to show up, it does not (where the arrow keys will continue to show ^[[A, etc.) This would lead me to believe it is able to handle the F1 key somewhere within the boot (to be expected for a boot program). Any explanation on how this mystery location could be getting the character code to show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a representation of the **F1** key...

Try for instance to execute a arbitrary command that hangs your terminal and then press F1. For example:

```
root@martinipc:somewhere/# read 
^[OP^[OP^[OP
```

As you see i pressed **F1** 3 times and then ^[OP appeared 3 times.

Maybe your machine required you to press the **F1** key before the point you are running, or maybe there is a temporary problem with the keyboard detection in the mother board, that is emulating the press of the F1 key.
Another possibility occurs if you pressed it only one time, but the system is with a lot of lag..  this can causes this strange behavior too, you press a and get something like aaaaaaaa.

Comment: Ok so extension on the mystery. I'm pretty sure these codes only return if the system does not know how to deal with the input. It only shows up at a random point during the installation--and when I try to hit the F1 key to force the ^[OP to show up, it does not (where the arrow keys will continue to show ^[[A, etc.) This would lead me to believe it is able to handle the F1 key somewhere within the boot  (to be expected for a boot program). Any explanation on how this mystery location could be getting the character code to show up?

Comment: What happen if you boot without keyboard and mouse or if you try to press F1 on the computer that does not has the problem? Do you have usb emulation for DOS enabled or some kind of compatibility option enabled on the mainboard? Efi and legacy mode affects the behavior? Your keyboard has the fn key to switch the f1 key up?